# Plotting Subset Time Interval R

Tags: r

Without using the zoo package, is there a way to use the `plot(date,variable)` command to restrict the time series for only a specific date range?

Reading through some prior posts, I have a few candidate:

`with`
`which`
`subset`

What is the best way to plot a subset time range of dataset?

Comment: The help page at `?zoo` shows how to subset in a few different ways. Why not use one of those. For example, with the `z2` example, you can easily subset like this: `z2[index(z2) >= "2003-01-02" & index(z2) <= "2003-01-03"]`

Comment: Thank you for the help. Out of curiosity. The `index` function in zoo only labels the elements linearly, so `index(z2)=1,2,3,4..` Why is it that we compare this linear ordering with the date `index(z2) >= "2003-01-02"`. Confused as to how R is reading the statement.

Answer (score 0):

Use *window()*:

```
x = ts(cumsum(rnorm(40)), start = c(2013, 1), freq = 12)
x.sub = window(x, start = c(2014, 1), end = c(2014, 12))

plot(x)
lines(x.sub, col = 'red', lwd = 2)
```

Or just use *xlim* to control the x axis display:

```
plot(x, xlim = c(2014, 2014.5))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `xts` package. It provides very easy way to subset the timeseries based on time ranges. In example below, `X` is a xts object. You can subset `X` by simple text `yyyymmdd HH:MM:SS` format.

```
require(xts)
X <- xts(1:100, order.by=Sys.Date()+1:100)
plot(X)
```

[image: plot(X)]

---

```
plot(X['201401'])
```

[image: plot(X['201401'])]

---

```
plot(X['201401/201402'])
```

[image: plot(X['201401/201402'])]

---

```
plot(X['20140101/20140115'])
```

[image: plot(X['20140101/20140115'])]